# How expensive is a motherboard with more than 10 DDR3 slots?

Tags: motherboard

I want to build a powerful server.

How expensive is a motherboard in which I can have 40GB RAM?

Comment: It will depend on where you are. Have you searched some online stores for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For more than 10 DDR3 slots, the main options are either 12 or 18. Of course a motherboard with this memory capacity won't come all that cheap, it also depends on where you live as prices will vary. For a general idea, [here is newegg's list](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=2010200302%201420246472&bop=And&ShowDeactivatedMark=False&ActiveSearchResult=True&Order=PRICE) of boards with 12 memory slots, sorted from lowest price to highest (prices in USD).

Comment: thanks for that . What sort of processor should i choose for that sort of motherboard

Comment: I'd go for a Xeon. Which one you choose is dependent on your budget.